# How can I add top answers from other sites?

Tags: support, status-completed, developer-story

Originally I was going to ask this as "Can we make the developer story a bit more generic?" But then I reread the Meta posts about it and realized, "Oh, it already is!" So my specific problem is the Top Answers feature only includes answers from SO. As my focus is not on programming, I'd like to show some of my greatest hits from Super User, Ask Ubuntu, and Unix and Linux. Would this be possible? Is it a bad idea for some reason I'm missing?

Also, is there a reason we don't allow anything but the top posts? What if I have an awesome second or third highest post?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily add any answer from Stack Exchange, just by entering the URL in the dialog box.

[image: add top answer]

This could be one of your not-top answers from Stack Overflow, or an answer from another site on the network.

Comment: Thank you, I apologize. I'm quite tired and out of it right now, almost as much so as I was when I asked how there could be a div inside a div that had a background image.

Comment: Is this an example of a good time to delete a question?

Comment: @DuncanX.Simpson I suspect others may have the same question.

Comment: Okay, I just missed that entire field right below the main part so I figured it would be obvious to others, but at your recommendation I leave it.

Comment: odd. when i first was checking that out a few days ago i wanted to put other SE answer in there but i was for sure i read *"Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Overflow"*. must have misread it